# Gmail to SSL secured domain port

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, dyndns

Here is the situation: I have a domain (it is **NOT** always-on) and I have configured port 465 as SSL-secured SMTP "e-mail receiver" (with [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/)) with a self-signed certificate (note that I have disabled port 25 for security purposes).

However, I get a warning message from Gmail saying that it cannot reach "my_domain:25". Doesn't Gmail try to send mail to port 465 using my self-signed SSL certificate? If it does, why haven't I received the "test e-mail" to my domain e-mail yet???

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing SMTP as used to communicate from a mail client to the SMTP server with SMTP as used to send an email from an MTA to another MTA?

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify a host name inside the MX record for your domain and the server is expected to listen on port 25. If you want to enforce TLS then you should set up your mail server, so that it only allows submission if STARTTLS is done before the submission. Any connections after STARTTLS are encrypted.

Comment: My version of HMailServer **DOESN'T** support STARTTLS, ONLY SSL, so can I use my port 465 or MUST I revert to using port 25?

Comment: You MUST offer plain SMTP on port 25 and you might offer the upgrade to TLS via STARTTLS.

Comment: But how can I support TLS on hMailServer?

Comment: If hMailServer does not support STARTTLS then you can not use it as the mail server published in the MX records.